# Application.yml to define beans for jar files

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans

I have a Spring boot application and an application.yml file. Now in order to read values from the application.yml I am using @Value annotation and it works fine.

The issue comes, when I try to read the application.yml file from a jar file. I have a jar file, and it is added as a dependency in the my spring boot application, now if I try to read application.yml file from the jar file using @Value I don't get anything.

Is there a way I can read the application.yml using the jar file dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

You could put the `application.yml` file outside the resources folder of your spring project and read it through any jar.

First boot your spring boot app with this command:

```
java -jar -Dspring.config.location=<path-to-file> myBootApp.jar
```

And you can read your file through your other jar by using a YAML library. There are
several libraries that you could choose from.

You could also check [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-properties-file-outside-jar) article for more info on reading the properties from outside your spring boot app.